# Consume only one record from table for processing when there are multiple process running in parallel

Tags: java, oracle

Let us say I have a batch table where it stores list of batched records.
The java process needs to pick one record (oldest) from the table for processing. Similar java process will be running in parallel in different machines

Use case: The second process should not pick the same record that the first one picked.

```
create table batch
(
 id number primary key,
 worker varchar2(32),
 status varchar2(32),
 created date
);


insert into batch values(1, null, null, sysdate);
insert into batch values(2, null, null, sysdate+6);
```

I am thinking of the following

1. Issue a update command to update one row on the batch table with
   predicate - status is null and worker is null.
2. If updated count > 0, fetch one record from table where worker = 'current worker' and status is in progress

```
update batch set worker = 'worker1', status = 'IN_PROGRESS' where
id = (
  select id from (
   select id from batch 
     where status is null and worker is null order by created desc
   ) where rownum = 1
) and status is null and worker is null;
```

```
select * from batch where worker = 'worker1' and status = 'IN_PROGRESS'
```

In this scenario, when the multiple java process issue an update command,

1. will the update statement be atomic and will it work as expected?
2. will there be any problems with this approach apart from the fact that the record might not be processed if the worker dies down.

Comment: Check Oracle [AQ](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_opers.htm#ADQUE2835) actually you are writing DIY dequeue.

Comment: @Marmite Thank you for Aq reference..I will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. will the update statement be atomic and will it work as expected?

Yes. But it's too complicated.

```sql
update batch set worker = 'worker1', status = 'IN_PROGRESS' where status is null and worker is null;
```

Database guarantees concurrency for this sql.
But the way I would recommend is to use MQ(Message Queue).
This is because a large number of threads or processes can degrade performance and cause deadlocks.
Refer rabbitmq and kafka.

2. will there be any problems with this approach apart from the fact that the record might not be processed if the worker dies down.

Yes. If a worker dies during processing, the message will remain in the DB unreferenced.
You will have to update those records yourself.

Using a DB for queue purposes is not a good idea.
Make sure you use the MQ.

Answer (score 3):

Each Java program needs to lock the records it has fetched, and also skip over any records that have been locked by another program. That can be achieved with the SKIP LOCKED clause.

So your Java programs open a cursor along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

As you fetch, if you hit an unlocked row, you will "get" it and lock it. If you hit a row that is already fetched (and hence locked) by another session, then it will not be returned to this calling program.

Comment: This is very dangerous. If a resource is not returned by an error or bug, it can be dead locked.

Comment: This is the way that AQ uses for [dequeue messages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_opers.htm#ADQUE2835) and is documented starting with [Oracle11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2126016). *My one new feature per day done for today, thanks;)*

Comment: I looked at it already..but as yeahseol said it could lock row if worker dies

Comment: no, it wont be deadlocked - thats something different - but it could be left locked if your program doesnt correctly handle cleanup.  But that is no different to any mechanism that locks the rows.  And if you dont lock the rows, you will run the risk of either missing some or doubling up.